# How to stop Setup Assistant from showing up on every restart on Mac Mini with OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, server.app, startup, setup-assistant

My Mac Mini is new.
I'm not sure if this issue was already there before installing Server.app.
Unsusual things happen with the system on EVERY RESTART: Messages Agent ask permission to use keychain to which I say "always allow" and it pops up again till I say only "allow"; Dock gets resete (all customization lost); it always notifies me that I can download iwork for free but I already did; it always asks for icloud password. It´s like it resets some stuff every startup.

Answer (score 2):

If Setup Assistant is running then the boot process almost certainly found no copy of  /var/db/.AppleSetupDone

Try `sudo touch /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` in Terminal then reboot.

If you are having trouble after that with strange parts of the install process staying around then you may have some widespread permission problems. Use `Disk Utility` to verify and then fix permissions on the volume and see how much that will fix after another reboot. You may find the problems still there on the first reboot after fixing them - it's the second that will tell.

I doubt if the Server app is causing anything as it really is just an application that provides a GUI for setting up some stuff already on your Mac.

Comment: I tried, then Terminal asks me for a password and it doesn´t let me write it, it´s like the keyboard is not working, unless you press enter and you get "sorry, try again".

Comment: Yes, the `sudo` command will want you to entor your password and won't echo anything to the screen. Just type it then press enter.

Comment: Ok. That solved the question. Thanks. Yet there's still unsusual things with the system on EVERY RESTART: Messages Agent ask permission to use keychain to which I say "always allow" and it pops up again till I say only "allow" I Dock gets reseted; it always notifies me that I can download iwork for free but I already did; it always asks for icloud password. It´s like it resets some stuff every startup. Does it have anything to do with Server.app? Any help here? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Expanded my answer to cover possible fixes for those.

Comment: Did permission repair twice 2 permissions didn't repair: 1-"Permissions diferent at “private/etc/aliases”; shoul be lrwxr-xr-x ; but are -rwxr-xr-x .“private/etc/aliases” repaired" (it was not repaired)Did restart twice only solved IWork notification. Still resets Dock and ask for passwords for keychain. Did repair permission inside Keychain.app fixed something but still it asks for passwords.
2-Warning:  SUID file “System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent” was modified and will not be repaired."

Comment: Did restart twice only solved IWork notification. Still resets Dock and ask for passwords for keychain. Did repair permission inside Keychain.app fixed something but still it asks for passowrds.

Comment: Dock is fine after reset found here: (http://superuser.com/questions/30236/how-to-reset-dock-items-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue after having installed Mavericks, then used migration assistant to transfer my data from a HDD to an SSD. I followed every guide I could find, and none of the fixes worked for me.

Eventually I found a file in **~/Library/Preferences** named **com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist**. In this file, I changed **ShowKeychainSyncBuddyAtLogin** to **NO**, **RunNonInteractive** and **DidSeeCloudSetup** to **YES**. This stopped the setup assistant from running for me, but now my dock won't save the fact that I don't want iBooks or Maps. I believe it is because of the **RunNonInteractive** flag, but am uncertain (and can't currently verify, as I'm making an image of my old HDD).

Answer (score -3):

system Preferences> click on bluetooth icon>click on advance tap on bottom >uncheck top two selections