# Permanently remove icons from Dock

Tags: dock

I have Maps, Photos and iBooks icons returning to my dock after a reboot even though I removed them several times already. Is there some way to remove them? They seem to be set as defaults, can I change these defaults somehow?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: I am running 10.11.3

Answer (score 7):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236466/110753) answers it partially.
When I encountered the same problem on El Capitan, these steps solved it.

1. Disable System Integrity Protection.
2. `sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete:add-app" /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/com.apple.dockfixup.plist
   sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete:add-doc" /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/com.apple.dockfixup.plist`
3. Re-enable System Integrity Protection.

I referred to [another discussion for PlistBuddy](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12266/os-x-yosemite-is-there-a-way-to-remove-persistent-apps-from-the-dock-for-newly-created-users#responseChild72032)

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. At first I didnt get it to work, but that was because I'd forgotten sudo (PlistBuddy fails silently if you do...)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. This finally worked, after I had tried several other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The property list is most likely corrupted. The following *will reset the dock to it’s default*, but it should subsequently allow you to modify it and have it work properly.

- Open Finder. Hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open a “Go To Folder” window.
- Enter the following path: `~/Library/Preferences`

  - Within the folder, move any file starting with the string `com.apple.dock` to your Trash.
  - Navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost` as well. Remove any file starting with `com.apple.dock` in the same manner.
- Log out of your account and log back in. The dock should be reset to default.
- Now, attempt to modify it:

  - Remove the unwanted dock icon(s)
  - Reboot, log back in to make sure the modifications are preserved.

---

Note that I'm assuming you are running 10.10 or higher.

Comment: The dock reset its position from left side to bottom after I deleted the files, but the dock icons still return after the reboot. Is it possible I have some device policy that is enforcing them (this is a work macbook).

Comment: @gruszczy Possible, but unlikely. Are you an admin. on the machine? I suggest logging in another user account and seeing if the behavior persists (Guest should suffice) in order to try and at least isolate the issue.

Comment: In an earlier version, I had to make Dock changes that could not be done by GUI.  I had to change the plist, but since Dock on exit write the plist with its current state, I had to kill -9 as soon as I had made the changes.

Comment: njboot: I can't seem to be able to log in as a guest. There isn't any option anywhere. But I discovered that I don't need to reboot, it's enough to log out + log in for the icons to appear again.

Comment: WGroleau: Could you walk me through the process of what you did?

Comment: @gruszczy if your account has admin. privileges, then you can create a new account to test the behavior (System Preferences > User Accounts). If you aren’t, I suggest having whomever is (the IT dept at your work) troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was a symptomatic treatment to change `dockfixup` behavior.
The true problem was that Setup Assistant (which triggers `dockfixup`) ran at every login.

This was caused by `~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist` in my case.

The file was not writable by me:

```
-rw-------   1 root  wheel  117  9 27  2016 loginwindow.plist
```

So I changed the owner and group to me:

```
sudo chown "$USER:$GID" ~/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist
```

(`GID` is a shell variable of your group id.)

[Removing the file will also fix the problem](https://lovemac.jp/blog/3136/).

Other questions such as [How to stop Setup Assistant from showing up on every restart on Mac Mini with OS X Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117753/how-to-stop-setup-assistant-from-showing-up-on-every-restart-on-mac-mini-with-os) may be useful if you see “Setting up Your Mac” in every login.